# Accessing global variable accross methods confusion in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

This is what I have:

```
class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public $extension;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->extension = "";
    }

    public function index($page_id, $extension=null)
    {
        if(!is_null($extension))
        {
            $this->extension = $extension;
        }
        $this->firephp->log($this->extension);
        $this->load->view('/modules/calendar_view', array("page_id" => $page_id, "extension" => $this->extension));
    }

    public function update_calendar($width, $page_id, $new_month=null, $new_year=null)
    {
        $this->firephp->log($this->extension);
    }
}
```

The correct value echos out in the index method fine, obviously. But the view it loads then calls the second method and the global variable is not set.

Is there a way of setting it until it's explicitly changed?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by global variable? Which one is that?

Comment: Ok, my terminology might be a tad off here! The one at the top, `public $extension`

Comment: I guess I could just use a cookie actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public $extension` is not a global variable here. I believe flashdata is what you are looking for

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

In your next call you can get the item as

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

These are flushed in next execution.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'd come accross them before but didn't put 2 and 2 together. All working now, cheers!